# What is this query language called

Tags: lucene, google-search, google-query-language

As I understand Apache Lucene and Google (GSA or GCS) are completely different search engines / frameworks and their parsers have varying logic but their query languages seem extremely similar, or the same. If they are the same what is this query language called? If not the same what is each called/what are the differences?

example:

```
field1:foo "some text"
```

and the item existed in the dataset

```
{
  "field1": "foo",
  "somefield": "bla bal some text"
}
```

would be in the result

Comment: Lucene uses by default its own classic query syntax and parser https://lucene.apache.org/core/8_2_0/queryparser/org/apache/lucene/queryparser/classic/package-summary.html#package.description. I don't know how it's working at google but it's probably quite the same. That said if the structure looks the same from one to another search engine, it's more likely because they use an inverted index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might call it "search syntax", it's kindof a mashup of the old days of information retrieval research  (80s and 90s) and what the suddenly dominant web search engines settled on in the late 90s.

Modern customer-oriented search engines match all the words in the query in all fields, although some allow partial matches.  Most allow ways to override the default behavior using query syntax such as Boolean operators like AND (sometimes "+"), OR (sometimes "||") and NOT (sometimes "_"), quote marks to indicate phrase search matches, and field filters like "department:".

After all that, it occurs to me that you may come from a database background, and be asking about why the result doesn't exactly match the query.  If that's the case, it's because the search engine has an inverted index that can match parts of fields, and then sort results by a relevance algorithm, usually TF IDF.

Comment: I do have a little db background, but the reason I ask is because I didn't know the term, as you say is "search syntax", for it independent of the implementation to use in conversation and more importantly for web searching (as meta as that is) when trying to do my own research to learn more about it. In-house we call it googley and on the web it seems a lot of people call it lucene but that could be confused with the implementation. I was hoping there was a standard technical term.